# Очередность выполнения cron команд

Tags: php, cron

Такая ситуация. Есть сервер на Linux. Там реализована генерация .txt файла и отправка этого файла на другой сервер. Все это выполняется каждый 3 минуты, с помощью команды в планироващике (cron):

> php /var/www/www-root/data/www/generation-txt.php; sh /var/www/www-root/data/www/otpravka.sh

То есть по идеи сразу должен выполниться скрипт `generation-txt.php` который запишет нужную информацию из базы mysql в txt файл, и только потом перейдем к выполнению второй команды(отправки файла на другой сервер), которая прописана в `otpravka.sh`

И все почти хорошо. НО, бывают такие случаи когда txt файл сгенерировался не до конца (не всю информацию записал) и уже отправляет файл на другой сервер, то есть выполняется вторая команда. Таким образом получается на другом сервере не полный txt файл, где нет части информации. А если открыть через несколько секунд этот-же сгенерированный txt файл на том сервере где он создается - он уже будет полный.

Почему так происходит и как это решить? чтобы отправляло на другой сервер файл только после того как скрипт его сгенерировал.

P.S. время выполнения php скрипта генерации файла может быть разное, от 7 до 30 секунд в среднем.

Comment: Может, php-скрипт просто падает с какой-нибудь ошибкой?

Comment: Почему нельзя запустить __один__ скрипт который и сгенерит и отправит?

Comment: попробуйте добавить между ними вызов программы sync. или вызывайте её в начале второго скрипта.

Answer (score -1):

Возможная причина в том, что файл все еще остается открытым для записи при завершении первого скрипта. Я бы убедился что все ресурсы освобождены, fclose вызван. А в конце еще бы поставил sleep() для верности.

Также можно разнести эти две задачи во времени. Скажем по четным минутам генерировать, по нечётным - отправлять. То есть сделать два задания в cron.

```
*/2 * * * * /generate
*/2 * * * * sleep 60; /send
```

Comment: в крон можно указать только с какой переодичностью выполнять( по крайней мере я так вижу, панель ISP